# what video formats supported by chromecast device (mp4,flv,m3u8,flv,avi)?

Tags: video-streaming, google-cast, chromecast

How we can send mp4,m3u8,rtmp,flv,avi urls from iphone to chromecast to play them? 
Are these format supported by chromecast ?

Do we need a specific iPhone app so it send mp4,m3u8,rtmp,flv,avi urls to chromecast?
OR
We can send media urls using iPhone chrome browser(i am not talking about screen mirroring here)?

If we can send direct media urls via iphone to chromecast device how about sending url of media page instead of actual media url will chromecast device play the media ?

Answer (score 3):

Supported media can be found on the developers site :

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media

Right now we support iOS native apps for casting content from iPhone/iPad.

Comment: Many thanks for reply. could you explain what apps you means ? only youtube app for iphone ? can developer create custom apps so user can send any media url from any website so chromecast device play it ?

Comment: Yes you can develop your own iOS app that cast your content from your  iPhone app to Chromecast.  A sample app can be found here: https://github.com/googlecast

Comment: is it possible to develop an iOS browser just like twonky beam iphone app so we browse any page and just click a cast button in that page so it send the media url(supported media url or supported direct media url not media page url) chromecast device instead of casting media from iphone to chromecast (twonky beam uses DLNA to send media)?

Answer (score 3):

As Paul indicated, the media formats supported by ChromeCast is limited. Video in other formats will have to be transcoded into the supported formats before sending it to the ChromeCast device. I've open sourced an app that does transcoding with VLC: https://github.com/entertailion/Fling

If you want to let the ChromeCast device load a web page with media embedded, be aware that ChromeCast does not support Flash. It does support web pages that use the HTML5 video player. To be able to load another page on a ChromeCast device you will have to write your own app and receiver html that will redirect to the page you want to load.

The easiest way to play media files that are not supported is to use the Chrome browser casting extension.

Comment: thanks guys for reply. Leon does iphone chrom browser work for casting any media ? or only windows chrome browser can cast ? i think android hdmi dangle support more video formats then chromecast!I wonder if google going to support more video formats or not!

Comment: The mobile chrome browsers don't support casting. The desktop versions of the Chrome browser do support casting.

Comment: Most of the videos are in the flv format from major video service providers. Do you have any idea if Chromecast is going to support the flv format?

Comment: Very likely not. Everybody is moving away from Flash.

Comment: i just wonder why google doesn't install full android on this chromecast ? or is it possible to install full android in chromecast ?Is is hardware limitation ?

Comment: The ChromeCast is low-end hardware in terms of the CPU. Google TV is their full Android solution.