# JwPlayer ChromeCast : Unable to Cast : Media format is unsupported

Tags: android, jwplayer, chromecast

I am using JW player in Android. I am able to cast .mp4 media file. I am trying to cast (format=m3u8-aapl-v3) media format but I am getting the issue like `Unable to cast: Media format is unsupported`.

I am casting Media file mobile to Android TV.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155806/what-video-formats-supported-by-chromecast-device-mp4-flv-m3u8-flv-avi), the media formats supported by ChromeCast is limited. Video in other formats will have to be transcoded into the supported formats before sending it to the ChromeCast device. Here's the list of the [Supported Media for Google Cast](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media). You may also check this [forum](https://plus.google.com/communities/115742157569103585450) for additional reference.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I am able to cast .mp4 (https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4) media file using JWPlayer (compile 'com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary:ccl:2.9.1').
But m3u8 (http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/bipbop/gear4/prog_index.m3u8) media format not able to cast show error: Unable to cast: Media format is unsupported

Comment: 2100 Loading failed. Please try again.
Unable to cast: Media format is unsupported 
E/ccl_VideoCastManager: [v2.9.1] onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated(): Unexpected Idle Reason 0
E/ccl_VideoCastManager: [v2.9.1] onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated(): Unexpected Idle Reason 0
 E/ccl_VideoCastManager: [v2.9.1] onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated(): Unexpected Idle Reason 0
E/CastController: RemoteMediaPlayer LoadResult: FAILED

Answer (score 0):

If we want to implement Chromecast with jwplayer then we have to update our jwplayer to 3.x version with new jwplayer key.  It will support .m3u8 media format like hls streaming.